# How to add multiple web apps into a single network so that vnet connected to one web app get accessed to other web apps as well

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, vnet

**Purpose:**
I am cracking an implementation done in Azure 2 years by my former coworker. I am not sure how I can make 3 different web apps use 3 unique DNS servers.

**What do I need to achieve:**

I have a virtual network in Azure which I have given DNS server as custom (I have added IP in VM DNS settings). I also have got 3 web apps under the same app server. Now I have connected VNet to web-app-1 via Networking settings.

I also need to link web-app-2 and web-app-3 to Vnet.

**What I need to achieve:**
Is it possible to make web-app-2 and web-app-3 access Vnet without adding that VNet to these web apps directly? Is there any way to make web-app-2 and web-app-3 to link with web-app-1 which is already connected to Vnet? Or is it only possible with connecting vnet to all web-apps via networking?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect app 2 & 3 (or all apps) via hybrid connection to a VM on a vNET(or on-prem network) . That way the apps have access to resources on the same network as the VM since the VM becomes a proxy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections

> Within App Service, Hybrid Connections can be used to access application resources in other networks. It provides access from your app to an application endpoint. It does not enable an alternate capability to access your application. As used in App Service, each Hybrid Connection correlates to a single TCP host and port combination. This means that the Hybrid Connection endpoint can be on any operating system and any application, provided you are accessing a TCP listening port.